# How do i get the value of a form generated by for loop

Tags: python, django

Please, I'm trying to create a tax calculator app, where user enters x number of appliances, after which x is saved to the database, then a form with x number of fields will be displayed on the same HTML page for user to fill in power of each appliances

**views.py**

```
def input_gadget(request):
if request.user.is_anonymous():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NumberOfGadgets(request.POST)
    user = request.user
    input_form = False
    if form.is_valid():
        gadget = None
        no_of_gadgets = form.cleaned_data['gadgets']
        current_user = request.POST.get('user')
        data = TaxDetails(gadgets=no_of_gadgets, user=user)
        data.save()
        input_form = True
        gadgets = TaxDetails.objects.get(user=user, latest=True)
        fields = range(1, gadgets.gadgets+1)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            for field in fields:
                power_input = request.POST.get(field)
                tax = 'value1 + value2 + value3'
                TaxDetails.objects.filter(user=user, latest=True).update(tax=tax)
                due = TaxDetails.objects.get(latest=True, user=user)
                context = {'due': due, 'form': form, 'input_form': input_form, 'fields': fields, 'user': user}
                return render_to_response('inputdata.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        context = {'form': form, 'input_form': input_form, 'fields': fields, 'user': user}
        return render_to_response('inputdata.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = NumberOfGadgets()
user = request.user
taxdetails = TaxDetails.objects.get(user=user, latest=True)
context = {'form': form, 'taxdetails': taxdetails}
return render_to_response('inputdata.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template**

```
<div id="profile_base">
        <div id="header">
            <h3 style="color: #fff; text-align: center"> Enter your data</h3>
        </div>

        <form action="#" method="post" name="main_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="main_form" value="no_of_gadgets" />
            {% csrf_token %}
                <p>Previous number of gadgets: {{ taxdetails.gadgets }}</p>
                <p>Your previous calculation was on: {{ taxdetails.creation_date }}</p>
                <p>Your previous tax was: {{ taxdetails.tax }}</p>
                <p>
                    {{ form }}
                </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="current_user" value="{{ user }}"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
            <a href= '/' > <input type="button" value="Cancel"></a>
        </form>
        <form name="data_form" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="calcuclate">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if input_form %}
                {% for field in fields %}
                    <p><label for="{{ field }}">Enter item {{ field }} power(in WATT)</label> <input type="text" name="{{ field }}"/></p><br/>
                {% endfor %}
                <p id="data_error"></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="Calculate"/>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    {{ due.tax }}
    </div>
```

The problem I'm having is getting the value of this generated x number of fields without saving these values into the database, using these values in some calculations.For example a user enters 5 as number of appliances, the page reloads and generate a form with 5 fields,how do i get the value of each fields to do a sum like *value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5* in my views.py ? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the number of keys in request.POST match x, aside from the added csrftoken?

Comment: sorry, I don't seem to get you clearly

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding you correctly, but it seems to me you want to get the number of form fields. Since they are all present in request.POST (along with the csrftoken key which you don't care about), why not just get the length of request.POST?

Comment: ok, now i get you. I'm not trying to get the number of form fields, but I'm trying to get the value in each field generated in the form by the for loop

Comment: Okay. May I ask why you don't want to put the values into your database? It is standard in Django to store values for later use in the database, especially because of how easy it is.

Comment: Well, let me say I don't want my database to be too long.I'm kind of feeling lazy to start typing so many lines of code